# How can i write a dropdown in .hbl?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, frontend

I'm working on a project where I need to do some changes. I want to add a dropdown to present some values in user end. I am new to ember, handlebars, and javascript. Please help me with this. I searched all over google for solutions and I raise this due to I couldn't find a solution.

This is the code,

```
{{#bs-modal id="new-idea" open=openModal title="NEW IDEA SEARCH" closeAction="close" body=false footer=false}}
{{#bs-modal-body}}
    {{#bs-form action=(action "submit") model=this}}
        <p>Find or Test Your Book Idea</p>
        {{bs-form-element autofocus=true controlType="text" property="idea" placeholder="Type your keyword"}}
        {{bs-form-element autofocus=true controlType="text" property="type" placeholder="Book or eBook"}}
    {{/bs-form}}
{{/bs-modal-body}}
{{bs-modal-footer  closeTitle="CANCEL" submitTitle="GO GET EM ROCKET!"}}
{{/bs-modal}}
```

This is the rendered interface,
[image]

Under "Book or eBook" I want to have a dropdown. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Looks like you're using custom handlebar plugins.

Comment: Take a look at [ember-power-select](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select), as a side note your question shows no attempt to solve the problem yourself, you are basically asking people on stack overflow to figure out your job for you.

Comment: @evolutionxbox This is written by a previous developer and he is not with us anymore. Do you have any idea how can I find what plugins using in here?

Comment: You're going to have to search your source code. https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

Comment: They were using the ember-bootstrap plugin, and refer to the package.json file to find the other used plugins.

Comment: You can use the [ember-selectize](https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-cli-selectize).

Answer (score 2):

Before you start searching google, you may start by reading the Ember.js docs...

Here is one example from [How to do a select (dropdown) in Ember 2.0?](https://balinterdi.com/blog/how-to-do-a-select-dropdown-in-ember-20/)

```
<select onchange={{action (mut vehicle) value="target.value"}}>
    {{#each vehicles as |vehicleChoice|}}
        <option value={{vehicleChoice}} selected={{eq vehicle vehicleChoice}}>{{vehicleChoice}}    
        </option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```